# How do I access the properties of an Excel WorkBook from within a VSTO Add-In

Tags: .net, excel, vsto

case where I need to work with an Excel workbook that I have opened using the VSTO ThisAddin protocol.  My code first copies a file from the ProgramData folder to a destination specified by the user, this workbook is then opened after which I need to be able to manipulate the workbook using standard Excel object model functionality.  Here is the relevent code:

```
      'Generate the tag management folder structure underneath the specified working folder
      'if it doesn't already exist
      '<yyyyMMdd_hhmm>_<SBM Reference>_<busbar number>_<substation name>_<voltage>
      If Not Directory.Exists(instanceFolder) Then
           Directory.CreateDirectory(instanceFolder)
      End If

      Globals.ThisAddIn.InstanceFolder = instanceFolder

      'Now copy the file into place and open in Excel
      File.Copy(Globals.ThisAddIn.TemplatePath, instanceFolder & "\" & filePart & ".xlsm")

      Dim xlb As Excel.Workbook = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Workbooks.Open(instanceFolder & "\" & filePart & ".xlsm")
      xlb.CalculateFull()
      xlb.Calculation = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCalculation.xlCalculationManual
```

The code opens the file as expected however I am at a loss as to how to access the workbook functionality.  The code falls over at 'xlb.calculatefull'.  It appears that none of the expected workbook properties are available.  How do I access the workbook functionality?

Kind Regards
Paul.